# How to create a global class instance in php, accessible from any script throughout a website

Tags: php, oop, woocommerce

I couldn't find the answer for this one in a while. But for my current project I would really love to have a class instance, which would be globally accessible from any website script, pretty much like `$woocommerce` variable in WordPress. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this case you should apply Singleton pattern. It should be like below script. For more information about Singleton, please ask Google.

```
<?php
class YourClass {
   private static $instance;

   private __construct() {
   }

   /**
    *@return YourClass
    */
   public static getInstance() {
      if (empty(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new self();
        **//maybe your $woocommerce here.**
      }

      return self::$instance;
   }
}


//And any PHP files
$singleton = YourClass::getInstance();
```

In most case, I prefer using Singleton to global variable, it let you easy maintain your code and well support from IDE.

Comment: thank you, i've ran across this [page](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html) as well ;)

Comment: Singleton is bad pattern. This just can use public static methods.

Comment: Hi Deep, I think there are good pattern totally and bad totally. Base on the case we will choose which one. In this case it can be done just using a static method.